# How to get last increment in laravel orm?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, increment

As the title said ,
If I had a `vendor` model , how to get the last increment in laravel orm ?

I already find the answer, but can`t trans it to laravel orm way.
Any idea? 
case 1:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;
```

case 2:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name'
```

Comment: can you check my answer below and accept it if it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear whether you want to retrieve the last inserted id right after the insert or at any given time so I will answer the latter as it is the least straight-forward.

As you write yourself, the last inserted id is not stored with the table itself but rather the table *information_schema.tables* which is why you cannot use the model to retrieve this information. You can however use the *query builder* in Laravel to do this.

```
$last_insert_id = DB::table('information_schema.tables')
          ->where('table_name', $table_name)
          ->whereRaw('table_schema = DATABASE()')
          ->select('AUTO_INCREMENT')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for getting the last inserted ID, you can use the "insertGetId" method of Laravel's query builder (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries)

Example:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```